# How can I pass data from a detail view controller to a master table view controller in a homework diary app?

Tags: objective-c, parsing, segue

I'm making a homework diary app.  From the home screen theres a button that will take you to a navigational controller which controllers a master table view controller. This "master view" is linked to the "detail view".  In the master table view controller there is a table view that I want users to be able to fill with their homeworks. There's an Add button at the top of this page that takes the user to the detail page which contains a picker view (to allow users to select the homework's subject), a textfield (to allow users to enter a description of the homework), and a date picker view (to allow the users to select a date when the homework is due in).  There's also a Save button on this page that will close the current "Detail View" and will take the entered information from the various elements on the page and stick them into the "Master View" table view. The table view cell would have a title label and a detail label.

I've looked for the last 4 hours about how to do this, but there's so many differing methods.  I think I should be using segues (a return segue?) but I have no idea how to pass the data from the master view to the detail view.

On a similar note, if there is existing homework in the table view list, I want the user to be able to click on the homework's row and for the app to open the detail view with the information about that specific homework in the correct elements.

I really appreciate this, I've put a huge amount of effort into this.

Comment: I cannot see the picture.. try posting it again. Is your app made from the Master Detail new project template?

Comment: Sorry I don't have enough reputation points to post pictures yet.

Comment: It's ok, though you can upload it on any public image hosting and link the image..  Is your app made from the Master Detail new project template?

Comment: I have a view controller (home page) which leads to a navigation controller, which is the root controller for the table view (which displays the list of homeworks), and then the Add new row button leads to a view controller that has the date picker etc (the view that allows the user to insert the new homework data).

Comment: Ok, so what exactly do you have working, and what is it that you dont know how to do?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/n1p56577tkwdhb3/storyboard.png 
So I can click on the Add button in the table view and a modal transition takes me to the detail view (the view where the user enters the new homework data). But that's all. I want to be able to hit save on that page and have that detail view disappear and return the entered data about the new homework to a row in the table view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an unwind segue for this if you're using a segue to go from the master table view controller to the detail controller. When you invoke the unwind from the detail view controller, prepareForSegue will be called, and you can get a reference to the destinationViewController (which will be your master table view controller). In the master, you can create a property (of whatever type is appropriate for what you want to pass back, perhaps an array in this case), and you set the value of this property in prepareForSegue.